# Is there a way to apply a different function to every row of a dataframe where the str value in a particular column decides the function?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple columns. One of the columns can have either value 'A' or 'B'. Depending on the value, I want to apply a specific function to every row. Is this possible in python? As in 'A' should map to function A and 'B' should map to function B.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `apply`.

```
df.apply(lambda x: func_A(x) if x[column_name] == 'A' else func_B(x), axis=1)
```

Comment: Cool, but what if I'm applying this function on a groupby object?

Answer (score 0):

Say you groupby a dataframe by a column named 'GP' which value is not 'a' or 'b' (another column named 'C'),
you could def a function used by .apply, like:

```
def use_A_or_B(gpdf):
    for idx_name, row in gpdf.iterrows():
        if row['C'] == 'a': 
            pass #use A specific function here
        elif row['C'] == 'b':
            pass #use B function here

    return gpdf
```

then

```
res_df = df.groupby('GP').apply(use_A_or_B)
```

Comment: The column that I'm using to groupby is different from the column that I want to check for a condition (inside the use_A_or_B function) and I get the error the truth value of the series is ambiguous. Use a.empty() , a.item(), a.bool(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: @SwetaRajan yup, because you put a seires in a single comparison, I will try to update my answer...

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. Although, is there an approach that is faster than iterating through all the rows? Like map?

Comment: I'm not sure it will be faster or not, but you can use somthing like `gpdf.apply(your_custom_func, axis=1)` in `use_A_or_B`  (`pd.Dataframe` has no `.map`, btw.)